# Getting a PHP input form arguments with JavaScript's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, forms, input, autocomplete

I am trying to build PHP `input` forms with autocompletion.

When a user types something into the form, a database should be searched and all the words matching what the user typed should be returned. I am trying to use Autocomplete from jQuery.

I've tried to use a dedicated PHP page as a source for the autocomplete function. Since there are many different inputs, I would like to write generic code to search the database. I am trying to send this request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ("name of the input form") 
FROM MyDB 
WHERE "name of the input form" LIKE '%value typed by user%'
```

The name of each input is the name of a column in the DB.

How do I get the input form's name to use it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you post more code snippets (the HTML form, jQuery, and the PHP) then someone is more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the tips, I am quite new here.

So here is the code in the php page with the form. Actualy, it is already a function :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() { 
            $( ".query" ).autocomplete({
                source: "function_lister_autocomp.php",
            });
        } );
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<?php   /*function that print the form*/
    function field($attribut, $fieldName) {
        $val='';
        if(isset($_POST[$attribut])){$val=$_POST[$attribut];} //if the users entered a value, reminds it

        echo'<tr><td>'.$fieldName.'</td>';
        echo'<div class="ui-widget">';
        echo '<td><input class="query" type="text" name='.$attribut.' value='.$val.'>';}
        echo'</div>';   
        echo'</td></tr>';   
    }
?>

</body>
```

So the source of the data would be the page "function_lister_autocomp.php". I would like to transmit both the value entered by the user AND THE NAME OF THE FORM to this page. Here is the code :

```
<?php

    $val = $_REQUEST["term"] //value entered by user
    $name = $_REQUEST["name"] //name of the form

//request sent to the base  
try {
        $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=X','X','X');
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {die ('Erreur : '. $e -> getMessage());}

    $answer = $bd->query("SELECT DISTINCT(".$name.") FROM SEQUENCAGES WHERE ".$name." LIKE '%".$val."%'");

    // fetch data
    while($data = $answer->fetch()) {
        $return_arr[] =  $data[0];
    }

    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

How to actually GET THE VARIABLE $NAME is my big problem...

If someone knows how to do, thank you very much :) !